# Get average of every group of n elements in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of numbers. 
I want to go through that array and calculate the average of every 3 elements and store those averages in a new array.

this is the code I have

```
         var total = 0;
          //my array with the numbers in
         for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
             {
                  total += arr[i];
             }

            var avg = total / arr.length;
            avgArray.push(Math.round(avg));
```

With this code I can only get the avarage of all the arrays elements. 
I need to make it every 3 elements. so the avgArray would show 
number1,  avg of the first 3 eleemnts 
number 2,  avg of the second 3 elements
number 3
etc

Can you please help me ?

Comment: `for(i=0; i < arr.length; i+=3) { for(total =0, j=i; j < i+3; j++) total += arr[j]; avgArray.push(Math.round(Math.round(total / arr.length)))}`

Comment: @hindmost Average of every 3 elements, not average of every 3rd element

Comment: use same for loop as @hindmost suggested but in total = arr[i] + arr[i+1] + arr[i+2] :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic approach would be to accept array and batch size and based on size, compute total of batch and divide sum by size to get average.

```js
function groupAverage(arr, n) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length;) {
    var sum = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j< n; j++){
      // Check if value is numeric. If not use default value as 0
      sum += +arr[i++] || 0
    }
    result.push(sum/n);
  }
  return result
}

var arr = [1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 89,"test", 2, 3, 6, 8];

console.log(groupAverage(arr, 3))
console.log(groupAverage(arr, 2))
```

Comment: @Downvoter, I just hope this is not a  revenge vote.

Comment: I have used your code before and it has always worked for me.Thank you it fixed my problem

Comment: @ned Glad I could help you :-)

Answer (score 2):

One potential approach, working with a functional approach (rather than procedural):

```
function averageEvery(arr, n) {
  // if we have neither an arr, or an n
  // variable we quit here:
  if (!arr || !n){
    return false;
  }

  // creating an variable by the name of 'groups'
  // using an array-literal:
  let groups = [];

  // while the supplied Array ('arr') still
  // has a non-zero length:
  while (arr.length) {

    // we remove the first elements of that
    // Array from the index of 0 to the
    // index supplied in the variable 'n':
    groups.push(arr.splice(0, n));
  }

  // here we return the Array of averages, created
  // using Array.prototype.map() to iterate over
  // the Arrays held in the groups Array:
  return groups.map(

    // here we use Arrow functions, 'group'
    // is a reference to the current Array-
    // element, the Array from the Array of
    // Arrays over which we're iterating:
    group =>

    // here we use Array.prototype.reduce()
    // to sum the values of the Array:
    group.reduce(

      // 'a' : the accumulated value returned
      // from the last iteration;
      // 'b' : the current number of the Array
      // of Numbers over which we're iterating:
      (a, b) => a + b

    // once we find the sum, we then divide that
    // sum by the number of Array-elements to find
    // the average:
    ) / group.length
  );

}

console.log(
  averageEvery([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3)
); // [2, 5]
```

```js
function averageEvery(arr, n) {
  if (!arr || !n) {
    return false;
  }
  let groups = [];
  while (arr.length) {
    groups.push(arr.splice(0, n));
  }

  return groups.map(
    group =>
    group.reduce(
      (a, b) => a + b
    ) / group.length
  );

}

console.log(
  averageEvery([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3)
);
```

If you want to get the rounded values of the averages, you could use the above code but with a modification to the `console.log()` statement:

```
console.log(

  // here we use Array.prototype.map() to modify the returned
  // Array, with Math.round() as the callback function; this
  // callback function receives three arguments:
  // array-element: the average number,
  // array-element index: the index of that number in the Array,
  // array-copy: a copy of the whole Array
  // Math.round() takes only one argument (the rest are simply
  // discarded), the array-element, and rounds that array-element
  // the rounded number is then returned by Array.prototype.map()
  // create a new Array of the rounded averages:
  averageEvery([1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3).map(Math.round)
);
```

```js
function averageEvery(arr, n) {
  if (!arr || !n){
    return false;
  }
  let groups = [];
  while (arr.length) {
    groups.push(arr.splice(0, n));
  }

  return groups.map(
    group =>
    group.reduce(
      (a, b) => a + b
    ) / group.length
  );

}

console.log(
  averageEvery([1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3).map(Math.round)
);
```

Or the above function could be modified to return the rounded-average at the point at which the function forms the averages to return:

```
function averageEvery(arr, n) {
  if (!arr || !n) {
    return false;
  }
  let groups = [];
  while (arr.length) {
    groups.push(arr.splice(0, n));
  }

  return groups.map(
    group =>

    // here we use Math.round() to round
    // the calculated number:
    Math.round(group.reduce(
      (a, b) => a + b
    ) / group.length)
  );

}

console.log(
  averageEvery([1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3)
);
```

```js
function averageEvery(arr, n) {
  if (!arr || !n) {
    return false;
  }
  let groups = [];
  while (arr.length) {
    groups.push(arr.splice(0, n));
  }

  return groups.map(
    group =>
    Math.round(group.reduce(
      (a, b) => a + b
    ) / group.length)
  );

}

console.log(
  averageEvery([1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3)
);
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var avgs = [];
sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  sum = sum + arr[i];
  if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0) {
    avgs.push(sum / 3);
    sum = 0;
  }
}
console.log(avgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a counter variable and increment it on each iteration.

```js
var counter;

for ...
conuter++;
if(counter % 3 === 0)
  // make some staff
```

Comment: Please use snippet only if code is working properly. If its a sample code and running it will give error, paste it as code section and not as snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` and `map()` to do this.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
var c = 0

var avg = arr.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
  if(i % 3 == 0) c++
  r[c] = (r[c] || 0) + e / 3
  if(i == arr.length - 1) r = Object.keys(r).map(e => r[e])
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(avg)
```

Comment: This feel over complicating the code. (*Just my POV*)

Answer (score 0):

You could add first the values and if it has the right count, make average.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    nth = 3,
    avg = array.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        var ii = Math.floor(i / nth);
        r[ii] = ((r[ii] || 0) + a) / (i % nth !== nth - 1 || nth);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(avg);
```

Comment: When the input array length is not divisible by 3 (say 20 items array) you are not calculating the remaining 2 items average but return their sum.

Comment: I would prefer giving their average of the remaining items though... What say you?

Comment: do you have an idea for the above?

Comment: Nina, `(r[ii] || 0) + a)/(i % nth !== nth - 1 || nth)` part makes this code probably impossible to maintain. It's very hard wired. However here is a much simpler way to do this. Just add `var rem = array.length % nth;` and then correct the above line to read like; `r[ii] = (r[ii] || 0) + a / (array.length - i >= nth ? nth : rem);` We only divide `a` and at each step with `nth` and add it to `(r[ii] || 0)`. Simpler ha?

Answer (score 0):

I won't post a code snippet, but try to explain their reasoning behind their code. 
One possible solution would be only adding the average after 3 iterations. They did it by using a counter and testing the counter modulo 3:

`if (counter % 3 == 0)
  {your code calc the average}`

If the counter modulo 3 = 0, thus dividable by 3 makes it a like: do a operation if the counter is dividable by 3.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a for-loop but instead incrementing by 3 everytime and push the average to the avgArray list

*Like this*

```
var avgArray = []
for(i=0; i < arr.length; i+=3) { 
    total = arr[i] + (arr[i+1] || 0)+ (arr[i+2] || 0) ;
    avg = total/3 ;
    avgArray.push(Math.round(avg) );}
```

Comment: This is normally the most efficient way to do this job. However your code is unfinished. Besides the typos, when an input in length not divisible by 3 like `[3,7,17,17,7,1,10,19,7,13,8,13,15,8,19,12,13,9,6,8]` is given, you get `NaN` as the last item of your `avgArray`.

Comment: @Redu true that. Use `arr[...] || 0` instead. Buy this will limit you to have a batch of 3 only.

Comment: tahnks @Rajesh used your method in my fix

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tail call recursive approach just for some variety;

```js
var         arr = Array(20).fill().map(_=> ~~(Math.random()*20)),
averageByGroups = (a,n,i=0,r=[]) => a.length-i > 0 ? averageByGroups(a,n,i+n,r.concat(a.slice(i,n+i).reduce((p,c,_,s) => p+c/s.length,0))) : r;
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
console.log(JSON.stringify(averageByGroups(arr,3)));
```